# Number Theory proof verification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

WTS: For any positive real number $n$ such that $n$ is not a perfect $k$-th power, $\sqrt[k]{n}$ is irrational.

**Case 1: $n$ is rational**

Let $n=\frac{p}{q}$ for two co-prime, positive integers $p$ and $q$ such that $n\neq a^k$ for some integer $k$ and rational $a$. Let $d_1$, $d_2$, $\cdots$, $d_{m-1}$, and $d_m$ be the positive divisors of $p$. Similarly, let $f_1$, $f_2$, $\cdots$, $f_{h-1}$, and $f_h$ be the positive divisors of $q$. Define a function $g(x)$ such that $$g(x)=qx^k -p.$$ Clearly, the only positive root of $g(x)$ is $\sqrt[k]{\frac{p}{q}}$. Additionally, by the Rational Root Theorem, the only possible positive, real, rational roots of $g(x)$ are $\frac{d_i}{f_j}$ for integers $1\leq i \leq m$ and $1\leq j \leq h$. Now, we have a different question to ask: does the equation $$\frac{d_i}{f_j}=\sqrt[k]{\frac{p}{q}}$$ have any solutions? Let's first assume that it does. Raising both sides to the $k$-th power, $$\frac{p}{q}=n=\left(\frac{d_i}{f_j}\right)^k.$$ Because $d_i$ and $f_j$ are integers, $\frac{d_i}{f_j}$ is rational. However, this contradicts the fact that $n\neq a^k$ for a rational $a$. Hence, $\sqrt[k]{n}$ is irrational. $\square$

**Case 2: $n$ is irrational**

Let $n$ be a real, irrational number. Assume $\sqrt[k]{n}$ is rational (i.e. $\sqrt[k]{n}$ can be expressed as the ratio of two co-prime integers, $r$ and $s$). $$\sqrt[k]{n}=\frac{r}{s}$$ Raising both sides to the $k$-th power, $$n=\left( \frac{r}{s} \right)^k=\frac{r^k}{s^k}.$$ However, because $r$, $s$, and $k$ are all integers, $r^k$ and $s^k$ are both integers. Therefore, $n$ must be rational, a contradiction. Hence, $\sqrt[k]{n}$ is irrational. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Only two words : Well done !

Comment: Thank you! I had to rewrite the proof because there was an error, and I wanted to make sure this new one was correct.

Comment: @Peter Not true. "$n$ is not a perfect $k$-the power" means $\, n \neq a^k\,$ for some *integer* $k$, so much more needs to be said.

Comment: @BillDubuque That's what I said: "Let =$\frac{p}{q}$ for two co-prime, positive integers  and  such that ≠^ for some integer  and rational ". I left it out of Case 2 because it is implied by the irrationality of $n$.

Comment: @BillDubuque I just said that because $n$ is rational in the first case. Case 2 is trivial, but by your definition, anything can be considered a perfect $k$-th power.

Comment: @Peter & Pen Oops, there's a typo in my prior comment , it should say ... some *integer* $a.\ $  Also I think you want to assume $n$ is an integer (this is the usual statement of the problem).

Comment: @BillDubuque It's okay. I assumed $n$ was **rational** and not an **integer** for two reasons: 1) Making the denominator of a rational number 1 would make it an integer, so it's more general, and 2) I also wanted to prove that the $k$-th root of a fraction was irrational if the numerator and denominator were not perfect $k$-th powers.

Comment: No, it's not ok. They way you posed it makes it *trivially* true. The (usual) way I mentioned is less trivial and requires the Rational Root Test (or closely related result such as unique prime factorization).

Comment: @BillDubuque I was excusing your typo. Also, I used the Rational Root Theorem, which is similar to the Rational Root Test. I showed that you don't even need the Rational Root Test because it contradicts a fundamental property of $n$.

Comment: Who is the author of the exercise?  What is their precise definition of "$n$ is not a perfect $k$'th power", i.e. not a $k$'th power of *what*, an integer or a rational?

Comment: @BillDubuque Nobody wrote it. It was just a curiosity I had. I see that it's trivial, but I just wanted to make it more formal. I defined it to be a rational, which is more general. I can see that definiting it as such makes it trivial now.

Comment: @Pendronator If you mean not a $k$'th power of a *rational* then it's a trivial one-line proof. Otherwise (the usual statement) you need to use the Rational Root Test or equivalent.

Comment: @BillDubuque I see that now. Thank you. I just wanted to see if this proof was correct.

Comment: Either you argument is (way, way) too long, or it is incorrect, but I can't determine  which is the case until you are more precise about which definition of $k$'th power you are using. Please clarify that in the question, i.e write "not a perfect $k$'th power of a xxx" where xxx is either "rational" or "integer".